# ExecuteReader returns no results, when inspected query does

Tags: sql, ado.net

Consider the following code:

```
        StringBuilder textResults = new StringBuilder();
        using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(GetEntityConnectionString()))
        {
            connection.Open();
            m.Connection = connection;
            SqlDataReader results = m.ExecuteReader();
            while (results.Read())
            {
                textResults.Append(String.Format("{0}", results[0]));
            }
        }
```

I used Activity Monitor within Sql Server Mgmt Studio on the database to inspect the exact query that was being sent.  I then copied that query text to a query editor window within SSMS, and the query returned the expected results.  However, `SqlDataReader results` is always empty, indicating "The enumeration returned no results."

My suspicion is that somehow the results are not being returned correctly, which makes me think there's something wrong with the code above, and not the query itself being passed.

Is there anything that would cause this in the code above?  Or something I've overlooked?

**EDIT:**

Here is the query as indicated by the SQLCommand object:

```
SELECT DISTINCT StandardId,Number 
FROM vStandardsAndRequirements 
WHERE StandardId IN ('@param1','@param2','@param3') 
ORDER BY StandardId
```

Here is the query as it appears in Activity Monitor:

```
SELECT DISTINCT StandardId,Number 
FROM vStandardsAndRequirements 
WHERE StandardId IN ('ABC-001-0','ABC-001-0.1','ABC-001-0') 
ORDER BY StandardId
```

The query is working against a single view.

When I ran the second query against the database, it returned 3 rows.

The SqlDataReader indicates 0 rows.

Comment: maybe you should show us the query and the what the tables are looking like, it's rather hard to tell what fails with no query/DDL. The code above is okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use Sqldata adapter instead of sqldatreader.

```
StringBuilder textResults = new StringBuilder();

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(GetEntityConnectionString())))
        {
            using (
                var cmd = new SqlCommand(
            "SELECT DISTINCT StandardId,Number" +
                "FROM vStandardsAndRequirements " +
            "WHERE StandardId IN (@param1,@param2,@param3)" +
            "ORDER BY StandardIdl"

       , conn))
            {

                var dSet = new DataSet();
                var dt = new Datatable();

                var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "ABC-001-0";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@param2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "ABC-001-0.1";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@param3", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "ABC-001-0";
                try
                {

                    da.Fill(dSet);

        dt = dSet.Tables[0];

        foreach(Datarow a in dt.Rows)
        {

            textResults.Append(a["StandardId"].tostring()).AppendLine();


        }

        Messabox.Show(textResults.tostring);

                }
                catch (SqlException)
                {
                    throw;
                }

       finally
                {
                    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open) conn.Close();
                }

            }
        }
```

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it is

```
WHERE StandardId IN ('@param1','@param2','@param3')
```

instead of this?

```
WHERE StandardId IN (@param1,@param2,@param3)
```

Parameters should not be quoted, not in the SQLCommand object.

Comment: I tried that, and got 1 row back.  However, I *should* be getting three rows.  So I think that might be part of the problem, but not all...

Comment: @morgan Why do you think you should be getting 3 rows? If StandardId is unique, I would think 2 rows max, given  `WHERE StandardId IN ('ABC-001-0','ABC-001-0.1','ABC-001-0') `  param1 and param3 are the same.

Comment: @morgan - textResults is also appending all the results together without any commas, pipes or other separator. All you get is one string, so it's hard to see if there are multiple results.

Comment: oops - that was a typo on the last param, should be ABC-001-0a. As for textResults, I was actually checking the output of the SqlDataReader for the # of rows, which is why I didn't notice that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Very nice behavior I've observed

I looked for errors in code:

```
 ... dr = command.ExecuteReader()  ... If dr.Read Then ...
```

and found that 'dr.Read' works fine, but...
when I mouseover on 'dr', to lookup for data, return values disappeared !

Answer (score 0):

Check your connection string and make sure you are not connecting as a user instance.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254504.aspx

Comment: Checked - there's no 'User Instance' in the connection string, and I'm not using Sql Server Express - this is going against a full SQL server instance.