# C# SqlDataReader not returing results after ExecuteReader()

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

I am retrieving data from SQL Server using code that has worked in other projects.  When getting to the `ExecuteReader()` section, it all works fine.... BUT if you step over into the using block, the reader goes from having data in the returned section to saying

> enumeration yielded no results

This only needs to return 1 row.

SO when I step past this line:

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
```

The object is populated data from the query. The values match that in the table.

When I go one more step I hover over reader in the above line and it says

> enumeration yielded no results

I cannot see any issues with my code and I'm stuck.

To make matters more confusing if I search for a ordinal position by name it works.  Meaning the metadata of the column names seems to be available but not the data.

All I want to do is retrieve a row of data from a SQL Server table and populate an object class defined in my app.

I have tried returning a simple select all, removing the parameters etc and it seems to not have any effect.

```
    public ConnectionDetails GetCustomerConnectionDetails(string Customer_GUID)
    {
        ConnectionDetails _conDetails = new ConnectionDetails();

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["someconstring"].ToString()))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select Customer_ID ,Customer_Connection_Alias ,Customer_GUID from dbo.Connections where Customer_GUID = @Customer_GUID", sqlConn))
            {
                //[Customer_ID] ,[Customer_Connection_Alias] ,[Customer_GUID]
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Customer_GUID", SQL.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Customer_GUID;

                sqlConn.Open();

                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        _conDetails.Customer_ID = reader.SqlStringValueNullCheck(reader.GetOrdinal("Customer_ID"));
                        _conDetails.Customer_Alias = reader.SqlStringValueNullCheck(reader.GetOrdinal("Customer_Connection_Alias"));
                        _conDetails.Customer_GUID = reader.SqlStringValueNullCheck(reader.GetOrdinal("Customer_GUID"));
                        _conDetails.Connection_Status = reader.SqlStringValueNullCheck(reader.GetOrdinal("Connection_Status"));
                        _conDetails.Connection_Date_Time = reader.SqlDateTimeValueNullCheck(reader.GetOrdinal("Connection_Date_Time"));
                        _conDetails.Connection_GUID = reader.SqlStringValueNullCheck(reader.GetOrdinal("Connection_GUID"));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        return _conDetails;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciate. Cheers!

Comment: Run SqlProfiler from SSMS what do you see in the query?

Comment: _"Meaning the metadata of the column names seems to be available but not the data."_ - I believe this is normal when you don't receive any rows back. It seems likely that your query results in no results.

Comment: `reader.Read()` reads the next row of data in memory. And you can access the data of that row only by using various GetMethods such as `GetString`, `GetInt32` etc.  Have look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464012/asp-net-datareader-values)

Comment: Did you try and use the SqlDataAdapter instead ? This behavior is usually witnessed with SqlDataReader. Check this for better understanding :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940350/executereader-returns-no-results-when-inspected-query-does

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `Customer_GUID`? Please show us the source code for `SqlStringValueNullCheck`. What do you expect `reader.GetOrdinal("Connection_Status")` to return and why? Please show us the `CREATE TABLE` script for `Connections` table.

Comment: use while(reader.read()) not if()

Comment: Why would `SqlDataAdapter` be better than `SqlDataReader`? The other question you have linked to doesn't really explain why one might work over the other, especially not when `SqlDataReader` will be used internally by `SqlDataReader`.

Comment: @Thameem That won't make a difference.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya , your answer was what helped me fix this.  My knowledge of sqldatareader was not good enough to realise that it doesnt store data.  It is now working. Thanks for your help!!!  How can I give you the answer vote so you get the points?